# Identify what type of leakage from car

Tags: leak

I have a leakage from my car that looks brownish. Not sure what it is. If anyone can guess that will be helpful. I have attached the pictures for closer look.

[image: leak]

[image]

Comment: Get some and smell it : engine oil smells oily, gearbox oil like cat’s piss... but does not look like water.

Comment: it is most likely oil,you need to keep an eye on the oil level and to find the source for the leak,how urgent it is to get it fixed depends on what is leaking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like motor oil, but one look under the car is worth a hundred guesses. Likely to be drops somewhere on the car bottom that will indicate where or at least the general location of the car that is leaking.